# Vue 3 - Get Mixin available in the whole app

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuejs3

I'm new to vue and I am trying to use Websockets for my project. In this case I try to get my websocket-plugin accessible from every component in my app so I thought I can go with 'provide' and 'inject'?

In my main.ts:

```
/* eslint-disable import/order */
import '@/@fake-db/db';
import '@/@iconify/icons-bundle';
import App from '@/App.vue';
import ability from '@/plugins/casl/ability';
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n';
import layoutsPlugin from '@/plugins/layouts';
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify';
import { loadFonts } from '@/plugins/webfontloader';
import router from '@/router';
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue';
import '@core/scss/template/index.scss';
import '@styles/styles.scss';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import webSocketMixin from './plugins/webSocketMixin';

loadFonts()

// Create vue app
const app = createApp(App)

// Use plugins

app.use(webSocketMixin)
app.use(vuetify)
app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(layoutsPlugin)
app.use(i18n)
app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
  useGlobalProperties: true,
})

// Mount vue app
app.mount('#app')
```

I am providing the websocket-plugin in my mixin:

```
import { WEBSOCKETURL } from '@/config';
import { useWebSocket } from '@vueuse/core';

export default {
  install(app) {
    const { status, data, send, open, close } = useWebSocket(WEBSOCKETURL, {
        autoReconnect: true,
        //heartbeat: true,
    });

    provide('$webSocket', { 
        status,
        data,
        close,
        send,
        open
    });
  }
};
```

And in my component I try to use the websocket-connection:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Email, EmailFilter, EmailLabel } from '@/@fake-db/types'
import ComposeDialog from '@/views/apps/email/ComposeDialog.vue'
import EmailLeftSidebarContent from '@/views/apps/email/EmailLeftSidebarContent.vue'
import EmailView from '@/views/apps/email/EmailView.vue'
import type { MoveEmailToAction } from '@/views/apps/email/useEmail'
import { useEmail } from '@/views/apps/email/useEmail'
import { useEmailStore } from '@/views/apps/email/useEmailStore'
import { useResponsiveLeftSidebar } from '@core/composable/useResponsiveSidebar'
import { formatDateToMonthShort } from '@core/utils/formatters'
import { PerfectScrollbar } from 'vue3-perfect-scrollbar'

const { isLeftSidebarOpen } = useResponsiveLeftSidebar()

// Composables
const route = useRoute()
const store = useEmailStore()
const webSocket = inject('$webSocket');

if (webSocket) {
  // Senden einer Nachricht über die WebSocket-Verbindung
  webSocket.send('Hello WebSocket!');
} else {
  console.error('WebSocket connection not available.');
}
```

But it always ends up in "undefined". webSocket is undefined and I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried it with importing provide/inject from 'vue' but nothing changed.

Does anybody can help?

Comment: It's not a mixin, it's a plugin, correct term gives a better search. It's supposed to work the way you did it, there's no other way around, considering that you use autoimport plugin and it works correctly,  otherwise should import provide and inject. Please, provide a way to reproduce. "undefined" - it cannot be just undefined, there should be a warning in the console there's no $webSocket provide token, or it should inject an object

Comment: @EstusFlask well i console.log(webSocket) and the output is "undefined". I could repair the error of injecting while providing it in my main.ts. 

app.provide("$globalWebSocket", globalWebSocket)

I just wondered, because I thought it should be working with the providing inside the plugin.

Comment: I see now. provide() is supposed to be used only in components. Should be app.provide() inside install(app) too, this is the reason install receives it as a param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, composition API should be used only in the body of component setup and related lifecycle hooks. There may be exceptions depending on the implementation of a composable, but that is so for `provide`/`inject` as it relies on component hierarchy.

Since `install` in Vue plugin is executed inside a component, `provide` isn't suitable there, and `inject` should cause a related warning when undefined value is injected:

> [Vue warn]: injection "$webSocket" not found.

This is the reason application instance is provided in install function, the plugin should contain:

```
  install(app) {
    ...
    app.provide('$webSocket', ...)
```